# Receiving a 403 Error When Making Custom Service Requests to Google APIs for Gmail Services in Node.js

Tags: node.js, axios, google-api, gmail, google-oauth

I have a class where I have defined many functions for getting some functionalities of gmail by using Google Api Outh 2.0 for Gmail. But while api calling in line 13 in function searchGmail, I'm getting 403 error. I double checked all credentials values and mapped values, but everything was correct. I'm getting accessToken on fly and then accessing it in other services by storing the value in "accessToken" variable.

```
searchGmail = async (searchItem) => {
        console.log(await this.accessToken)
        var config1 = {
            method: "get",
            url:
                "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=abc@gmail.com", 
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${await this.accessToken}`,
            },
        };
        var threadId = "";

        await axios(config1)
            .then(async function (response) {
                threadId = await response.data["messages"][0].id;

                console.log("ThreadId = " + threadId);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });

        return threadId;
};
```

The code for dynamically getting tokenAccess,

```
getAcceToken = async () => {
        var data = qs.stringify({
            client_id,
            client_secret,
            refresh_token,
            grant_type: "refresh_token",
        });
        var config = {
            method: "post",
            url: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            },
            data: data,
        };

        let accessToken = "";

        await axios(config)
            .then(async function (response) {
                accessToken = await response.data.access_token;

                // console.log("Access Token " + accessToken);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });

        return accessToken;
    };
```

Error object caught in catch block in searchMail function,

```
  AxiosError: Request failed with status code 403
    at settle (C:\SAM\openingApp\node_modules\axios\dist\node\axios.cjs:1913:12)
    at Unzip.handleStreamEnd (C:\SAM\openingApp\node_modules\axios\dist\node\axios.cjs:3008:11)
    at Unzip.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST',
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [ 'xhr', 'http' ],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    env: { FormData: [Function], Blob: [class Blob] },
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: Object [AxiosHeaders] {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': undefined,
      Authorization: 'Bearer ya29.a0AfB_byBHy5Xv8kRZMLoDMHzL2DdnMZ6HgMdHcaHpYVLKN47Ej1PTg6mEXEExpFUWp7qwAdeMrfW8vHdGsOW0RTWhXKuUftFjWw2TeKQc
iFx_eL9-FhTpXJt7pLeSKtAusiuB_atsO8zKG3jK_cRP1CTXL5wp_OXb7eI8owaCgYKAVkSARESFQGOcNnCoZ4utKgMpqTNrqP1p9DvCA0173',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/1.6.0',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, compress, deflate, br'
    },
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=from:riddlerhp852@gmail.com',
    data: undefined
  },
  request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      abort: [Function (anonymous)],
      aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
      connect: [Function (anonymous)],
      error: [Function (anonymous)],
      socket: [Function (anonymous)],
      timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
      finish: [Function: requestOnFinish]
    },
    _eventsCount: 7,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    destroyed: true,
    _last: true,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: false,
    maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
    _defaultKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      strictContentLength: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      _closed: true,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      _header: 'GET /gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=from:riddlerhp852@gmail.com HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'Authorization: Bearer ya29.a0AfB_byBHy5Xv8kRZMLoDMHzL2DdnMZ6HgMdHcaHpYVLKN47Ej1PTg6mEXEExpFUWp7qwAdeMrfW8vHdGsOW0RTWhXKuUftFjWw2TeK
QciFx_eL9-FhTpXJt7pLeSKtAusiuB_atsO8zKG3jK_cRP1CTXL5wp_OXb7eI8owaCgYKAVkSARESFQGOcNnCoZ4utKgMpqTNrqP1p9DvCA0173\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/1.6.0\r\n' +
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
        'Host: www.googleapis.com\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
      path: '/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=from:riddlerhp852@gmail.com',
      _ended: true,
      res: [IncomingMessage],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'www.googleapis.com',
      protocol: 'https:',
      _redirectable: [Writable],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kEndCalled)]: true,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype],
      [Symbol(errored)]: null,
      [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
    },
    data: { error: [Object] }
  }
}
```

Comment: 403 what? What is the full error message

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo I have added the the error object, usually 403 signifies unauthorize access of any resource.

Comment: remove ?q=abc@gmail.com and let me know what happends

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo getting same error

Comment: Sorry I can't help much I don't have any samples for axios

Comment: Have you verified that `response.data` in `getAcceToken()` is returning a structure that contains the tokens you're expecting? Can you update  the question to include the (sanitized) value of `response.data`?

Comment: Also, what is `qs` that you're using to call `qs.stringify()`?

Comment: The issue has been resolved, I had to just authentic myself by requesting for Gmail api service and wait for 1 hour.